# Implementing a stack for an RPN calculator in NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I'm a NASM beginner and I'm currently working on implementing a RPN calculator in NASM.

My first objective was to implement a stack where I will save operands , and here's my first attempt: (My code is not complete, some function weren't written completely)

```
section .bss
STKSZ: equ 0xFF
STK: resb STKSZ

section .data
OSP: dd STK+STKSZ                   ; operand stack pointer points to beginning of predefined stack of size 255 bytes
debugMode: dd 0                     ; debug mode is set to OFF
promptMsg: db "calc: ",0

section .text
  align 16
  global main
  extern printf
  extern fprintf 
  extern fflush
  extern malloc 
  extern calloc 
  extern free 
  extern gets 
  extern getchar 
  extern fgets 

;Stack functionality: 
; _push, _pop , _isEmpty, _isFull

_push:
    push ebp                        ; function prologue
    mov ebp, esp

    push edx                        ; save registers I'm going to utilize for the sake of this         
operation

    mov edx, [ebp+8]                ; getting function's arguments to push onto our Stack impl.

    sub [OSP], 4                    ; push contents of edx onto stack 
    mov [[OSP]], edx                ; [OSP] is stack pointer, and [[OSP]] is what it actually contains? . Is this how I should do it?

    pop edx

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret  

myCalc:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    pushad

prompt:                             ; short piece of code to print a prompt to the user
    pushad
    push promptMsg
    call printf
    add esp, 8
    popad

read:




    jmp prompt                      ; loop around 


main:
```

I doubt my _push implantation is correct, Is there any better way of doing it? Also what if I wanted to use a user defined size of Stack to not have a stack that's almost completely empty? rather than the maximum 255 bytes I'm allocating in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main issue in your code is the `mov [[OSP]], edx`.  You cannot use a variable from memory directly as an address for another variable.

You are probably thinking primarily in terms of variables (as in high-level languages), whereas in assembler you want to work as much as possible with registers.  Every bit of data that is manipulated needs to be loaded into the processor first.  So, an innocent looking instruction like `sub [OSP], 4` is actually three instructions as far as the cpu is concerned (where `TMP` is an internally used termporary register):

```
mov   TMP, [OSP]    # load the variable into a register
sub   TMP, 4        # do the actual computation
mov   [OSP], TMP    # store the result to memory
```

When the cpu is accessing memory at a specific address, it must know the address, i.e. the address must be *inside the cpu*—either as a constant value or inside a register.  In the case of `mov [[OSP]], edx`, the destination address is still somewhere in memory (namely in the variable `OSP`) and not inside the cpu, so it cannot perform the operation.

What you want to do is something like:

```
mov   ebx, [OSP]   # load the address to `ebx`
mov   [ebx], edx   # store the contents of edx in memory
```

Here, you load the destination address for the second instruction into a register first, so that the address is available to the cpu.

However, since you need an extra register to load the current stack pointer, anyway, it might be a good idea to merge it with the previous instruction and do:

```
mov   ebx, [OSP]
sub   ebx, 4
mov   [OSP], ebx
mov   [ebx], edx
```

Finally, even better would be to keep your operand stack pointer (OSP) inside a register at all times, anyway.  Just assign something like `ebx` or `esi` to be your OSP, and work with it directly.  For a stack-based machine, you are probably accessing the stack all the time, anyway, and will need that value in virtually any computation.

By the way: most modern programming languages follow a convention where `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` are always free to be modified by any function.  If you call a function with two 32-bit values as parameters, you put them into `eax` and `ecx`, respectively, instead of pushing everything to the stack.  If you follow this overall scheme, you do not need to save `edx` inside your function (because every function is free to use it anyway), and in fact you do not even need a stack frame.  You could end up having a `_push` function that takes the argument to push in `eax` and is as simple as:

```
_push:
    sub    ebx, 4
    mov    [ebx], eax
    ret
```

**UPDATE:**  Concerning the stack size: yes, you can use `malloc`, of course, to have any size you want (as long as it is black, that is ;-)).  You will have to look up the exact call format of `malloc`, but I assume you put in the desired size in `eax` and get a pointer back in `eax` as well.  If you then want to put your stack pointer into `esi`, say, you initialise it as follows:

```
mov   eax, stack_size    ; whatever size you need
call  malloc
                         ; 'eax' is now a pointer to the new memory
mov   esi, eax           ; move the stack pointer to the end of
add   esi, stack_size    ; the new memory
...                      ; ready to go
```

Just make sure to keep in mind that if you request 1024 bytes, your stack will only have space for 256 entries as each entry takes four bytes.

Comment: is it a good idea to have my function arguments in a register though ? Isn't it conventional to have the arguments on the stuck before a function call? especially if I wanna have more than just one argument. 
Aside from that, thanks for your reply I get what I was doing wrong. Is there a way to have the size of the stack received as a command line argument? And since I wanna use ESI for say as my stack pointer, how would I go about initializing it? would that occur in the main function?

Comment: @sadElephent  Yes, it is usually a good idea to have the function arguments in registers--as long as this is possible, anyway.  If the argument is a floating point value, you cannot put that into `eax`, of course.  But `eax` might then serve as a pointer to the actual value.  And if you have more than three arguments, you put the rest of them onto the stack as usual (although most functions need three or less parameters).

Comment: Note that while there are architectures where something like `mov [[OSP]], edx` is possible, x86 is not one of them.